# latex article cls

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, documentclass-writing

I'm developing a template for an article in Latex using specific class. I have a problem showing 4 errors when compiling. Attached the predefined class together with the tex source file.

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance!
The main tex file "**file.tex**"

```
\documentclass[templateart,PDF]{templateart} 
\usepackage{layout}

\title{Title }

\articletype{Article} 

\author{First~Author\inst{1}\email{email@first.author.com},
        Second~Author\inst{2}\email{email@second.author.com}
       }

\shortauthor{F. Author, S. Author}

\institute{\inst{1}
           Department of Mathematics, University Full Name, Street, Postal code, City, Country
           \inst{2}
           Institute of Mathematics, Research Institution, Street, Postal code, City, Country
          }

\abstract{abstract abstractabstract abstractabstractabstract abstractabstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract abstract
}

\keywords{Keywords}

\msc{XXXXX, YYYYY}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\baselinestretch{2}


\vspace{5mm}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Section}

\end{document}
```

The cls file name is "**templateart.cls**":

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{templateart}
\newif\iftemplateart@twocolumns\templateart@twocolumnstrue
\newif\iftemplateart@printpagenumbers\templateart@printpagenumberstrue
\newif\iftemplateart@printlinenumbers\templateart@printlinenumbersfalse
\newif\iftemplateart@printpagerange\templateart@printpagerangetrue
\newif\iftemplateart@printbox\templateart@printboxfalse
\newif\iftemplateart@printabstract\templateart@printabstracttrue
\newif\iftemplateart@printkeywords\templateart@printkeywordstrue
\newif\iftemplateart@printpacs\templateart@printpacstrue
\newif\iftemplateart@printmsc\templateart@printmsctrue
\newif\iftemplateart@final\templateart@finaltrue
\newif\iftemplateart@pdf
\templateart@pdftrue
\pdfoutput=1
\newif\iftemplateart@firstaffiliation
\templateart@firstaffiliationtrue
\newdimen\templateart@tempdimen
\newcount\templateart@tempcount
\def\templateart@journalname{[{\tt templateart}]}

\def\templateart@shortjournalname{[ {\tt templateart}]}



\def\templateart@title{[Put the title here using command {\tt\char`\\title\char"7B text~of~title\char"7D}.]}
\let\templateart@shorttitle=\empty
\def\templateart@author{[Put the names of authors here using command {\tt\char`\\author\char"7B names of authors\char"7D}.]}

\let\templateart@shortauthor=\empty
\def\templateart@articletype{[Put the type of article here using command {\tt\char`\\articletype\char"7B type of article\char"7D}.]}

\def\templateart@year{[Put the year here using command {\tt\char`\\year\char"7B YYYY\char"7D}.]}

\def\templateart@issue{[Put the issue here using command {\tt\char`\\issue\char"7B NN\char"7D}.]}
\def\templateart@institute{[Put the names of institutes here using command {\tt\char`\\institute\char"7B names of institutes\char"7D}.]}
\let\templateart@msc=\empty
\let\templateart@pacs=\empty



\DeclareOption{templateart}{
  \def\templateart@journalname{Journal {\bfseries Name}}
  \def\templateart@shortjournalname{Journal Nmae}
  \def\templateart@type{templateart}
  \templateart@twocolumnsfalse
}

\DeclareOption{PDF}{\templateart@pdftrue\pdfoutput=1\relax}
\DeclareOption{DVI}{\templateart@pdffalse\pdfoutput=0\relax}

\ProcessOptions
\iftemplateart@printabstract   \templateart@printboxtrue \fi
\iftemplateart@printkeywords  \templateart@printboxtrue  \fi
\iftemplateart@printpacs   \ifx\templateart@pacs\empty   \else     \templateart@printboxtrue   \fi \fi
\iftemplateart@printmsc   \ifx\templateart@msc\empty   \else     \templateart@printboxtrue   \fi \fi
\LoadClass[10pt,twoside,pre,nofootinbib,secnumarabic,balancelastpage,superscriptaddress,showpacs,showkeys]{revtex4}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \pagestyle{myheadings}
  \def\contentsname{Contents}
  \def\listfigurename{List of Figures}
  \def\listtablename{List of Tables}
  \def\refname{References}
  \def\indexname{Index}
  \def\figurename{Figure}
  \def\tablename{Table}
  \def\partname{Part}
  \def\appendixname{Appendix}
  \def\abstractname{Abstract}

  \renewcommand*\email[1][E-mail: ]{\begingroup\sanitize@url\@email{#1}}%
  \chardef\*180
  \def\author#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname templateart@author\endcsname{#1}}
  \def\shortauthor#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname templateart@shortauthor\endcsname{#1}}
  \def\title#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname templateart@title\endcsname{#1}}
  \def\shorttitle#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname templateart@shorttitle\endcsname{#1}}
  \def\articletype#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname templateart@articletype\endcsname{#1}}
  \def\year#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname templateart@year\endcsname{#1}}
  \def\issue#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname templateart@issue\endcsname{#1}}
  \def\institute#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname templateart@institute\endcsname{#1}}
  \def\msc#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname templateart@msc\endcsname{#1}}
  \def\pacs#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname templateart@pacs\endcsname{#1}}
  \long\def\abstract#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname templateart@abstract\endcsname{#1}}
  \def\keywords#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname templateart@keywords\endcsname{#1}
  }
  \def\firstpage{\setcounter{page}}
  \def\lastpage#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname templateart@lastpage\endcsname{#1}}
  \def\titleblock@produce{%
    \def\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \begingroup
    \null
    \vskip-\baselineskip
    \vskip-12mm
      \vbox to0pt{\vskip-12mm
      }
      \vskip-\baselineskip
      \vbox to0pt{\vskip19mm \vskip\textheight
      }
    \vskip-\baselineskip
    
   
   
%% Top Header:    
    \vbox to0pt{\vskip-5mm \fontsize{7pt}{8.4pt}\selectfont    
      \templateart@shortjournalname\\
      \footnotesize{v. xx no.  xx, }\iftemplateart@printpagerange\;\thepage-\templateart@lastpage\fi , (2022)\\
       doi:00.0000/00000000000000\\
        \templatearthref[templateart@color]{https://www.website.com/journals}{https://www.website.com/journals}%
    }
    
    

    \vskip0.5mm
  
%%line at the header 
    \leftline{\hskip-2mm\color{templateart@color}\vrule width\@rulewidth height.5pt}
    %\vskip2pt


%% Journal Logo:   
\pretitle{
   \begin{flushright}
   \vskip -5.2em
   \includegraphics[width=30mm]{picture.jpg}  
  % \hspace{0.3em} \qquad\\
  \end{flushright}
}
 \vskip -1.2em 
 \hspace{5.35in}\scriptsize{This is a Logo}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \newdimen\@rulewidth
    \@rulewidth=\textwidth
    \advance\@rulewidth by4mm
    \vskip2.5mm
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{flushleft}
      \sloppy\fontsize{19pt}{22.8pt}\selectfont\color{templateart@color}\textbf{\templateart@title}
    \end{flushleft}
    \vskip-\baselineskip
    \vskip6mm
    \begin{flushright}
       \fontsize{9pt}{8pt}\selectfont\textbf{\templateart@articletype}
    \end{flushright}%
   \vskip-\baselineskip
    \leftline{\hskip-2mm\color{templateart@color}\vrule width\@rulewidth height.5pt}
    \vskip-1.5\baselineskip
    \vskip2mm
    \null
    
    
    \begin{flushleft}
      \def\inst##1{$^\text{##1}$}%
      \def\email##1{\footnote{E-mail: ##1}}%
      \fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont\textbf{\templateart@author}
    \end{flushleft}
    \null
    \vskip-2.5\baselineskip
    \vskip2mm
    \null
    \begin{flushleft}
     $\null$%
     \def\inst##1{\parindent=10pt%
       \iftemplateart@firstaffiliation%
         \vskip-\baselineskip
         \templateart@firstaffiliationfalse
       \else
         \vskip2mm
       \fi%
       $\null$\llap{\hbox to\parindent{##1\hss}}\ignorespaces}%
       \fontsize{8pt}{9.5pt}\selectfont\color{grey}%
      \vskip-1\baselineskip\indent$\null$\templateart@institute
    \end{flushleft}
    \vskip-1.5\baselineskip
    \vskip10mm
     \iftemplateart@printbox%
        \vskip-\baselineskip
        \vskip1.5mm
        \leftline{\hskip-2mm\color{templateart@color}\vrule width\@rulewidth height.5pt}
        \vskip-.5pt
        \fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont
        \settowidth\templateart@tempdimen{\textbf{MSC:}\kern.5em}%
        \iftemplateart@printabstract%
          \settowidth\templateart@tempdimen{\textbf{Abstract:}\kern.5em}%
        \fi%
        \iftemplateart@printkeywords%
          \settowidth\templateart@tempdimen{\textbf{Keywords:}\kern.5em}%
        \fi%
        \iftemplateart@printpacs%
            \ifx\templateart@pacs\empty%
            \else%
              \settowidth\templateart@tempdimen{\textbf{PACS (2008):}\kern.5em}%
            \fi%
          \fi%
          
%abstract box:
        \leftline{%
          \hskip-2mm\colorbox{abs}{%
            \hskip1mm\vbox{%
              \iftemplateart@printabstract%
                  \vskip2.6mm\hangindent\templateart@tempdimen
                   \fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont
                    $\null$\rlap{\textbf{Abstract:}}\kern\templateart@tempdimen%
                    \selectfont\templateart@abstract
                    \vskip1mm
                \fi%
              \iftemplateart@printmsc%
                  \ifx\templateart@msc\empty\else
                    \vskip1mm\hangindent\templateart@tempdimen
                     \fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont
                      $\null$\rlap{\textbf{MSC:}}\kern\templateart@tempdimen%
                      \selectfont\templateart@msc
                    \vskip1mm
                  \fi%
                \fi%
                \iftemplateart@printpacs%
                  \ifx\templateart@pacs\empty\else
                    \vskip1mm\hangindent\templateart@tempdimen
                      \fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont
                      $\null$\rlap{\textbf{PACS (2008):}}\kern\templateart@tempdimen%
                      \selectfont\templateart@pacs
                    \vskip1mm
                  \fi%
                \fi%
                \iftemplateart@printkeywords%
                  \vskip1mm\hangindent\templateart@tempdimen
                  \fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont
                    $\null$\rlap{\textbf{Keywords:}}\kern\templateart@tempdimen%
                    \selectfont\templateart@keywords\\[1mm]%
                  \vskip1mm
                \fi%
            \vskip1.6mm
            }%
          \hskip1mm}%
        }%
      \fi%
    \vskip-2mm
    \leftline{\hskip-2mm\color{templateart@color}\vrule width\@rulewidth height.5pt}
    \vskip10mm
    \endgroup
    \gdef\thefootnote{\@arabic\c@footnote}
    \global\c@footnote=0
  }%

  \def\@hangfrom@section#1#2#3{\@hangfrom{#1#2}{#3}}%
  \def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{19\p@}{12\p@}
    {\noindent\fontsize{15pt}{17pt} \bfseries \selectfont$\null$\color{templateart@color}}}
  \def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}{14\p@}{8\p@}
   {\noindent\fontsize{12\p@}{14\p@} \bfseries \selectfont$\null$\color{templateart@color}}}
  \def\subsubsection{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{8\p@}{4\p@}
    {\noindent\fontsize{10pt}{12pt} \bfseries \selectfont$\null$\color{templateart@color}}}
  \def\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{12\p@}{2\p@}
    {\noindent\fontsize{9pt}{12pt}  \bfseries \itshape \selectfont$\null$\color{templateart@color}}}
  \def\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}{6\p@}{\z@}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
  \c@tocdepth=1
  \c@secnumdepth=3

  \def\footnoterule{\kern-7.5mm {\color{templateart@color}\hbox{\hskip-2mm\vrule width79.8mm height.5pt}}\kern2mm}
  \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\parindent0\p@\relax\indent%
    \rmfamily\it\fontsize{9}{10.8}\selectfont%
    \@makefnmark\enspace#1}
  \def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
    \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
    \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}
  \def\thefootnote{\@arabic\c@footnote}
  \footnotesep=2mm
  \gdef\@reinserts{%
    \ifvoid\footins\else\insert\footins{\unvbox\footins}\fi
    \ifvbox\@kludgeins\insert\@kludgeins
                        {\unvbox\@kludgeins}\fi
  }
  
  
  \def\thetable{\@arabic\c@table}
  \abovecaptionskip=5.5mm
  \belowcaptionskip2mm
  \long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
    \par
    \vskip\abovecaptionskip
    \begingroup
    \small\rmfamily
    \sbox\@tempboxa{%
      \let\\\heading@cr
        \fontsize{9pt}{8.4pt} \bfseries \selectfont%
      \settowidth\templateart@tempdimen{#1.\enspace}%
      \hangindent\templateart@tempdimen{\color{templateart@color}#1.\enspace}%
    \fontsize{7pt}{8.4pt} \selectfont%
      #2\par
    }%
    
    \@ifdim{\wd\@tempboxa >\hsize}{%
      \begingroup
      \samepage
      \flushing
      \let\footnote\@footnotemark@gobble
      \fontsize{9pt}{8.4pt}  \selectfont%
      \settowidth\templateart@tempdimen{#1.\enspace}%
      \hangindent\templateart@tempdimen{\color{templateart@color}#1.\enspace}%
       \fontsize{7pt}{8.4pt}\selectfont%
      #2\par
      \endgroup
    }{%
      \global \@minipagefalse
      \hb@xt@\hsize{\unhbox\@tempboxa\hfil}%
    }%
    \endgroup
    \vskip\belowcaptionskip
  }%

  \renewenvironment{widetext@grid}{%
    \par\ignorespaces
    \setbox\widetext@top\vbox{%
    \vskip10\p@
    \hb@xt@\hsize{%
      \leaders\hrule\hfil
      \vrule\@height6\p@
    }%
    \vskip6\p@
    }%
    \setbox\widetext@bot\hb@xt@\hsize{%
      \vrule\@depth6\p@
      \leaders\hrule\hfil
    }%
    \onecolumngrid
    \dimen@\ht\widetext@top\advance\dimen@\dp\widetext@top
    \cleaders\box\widetext@top\vskip\dimen@
    \let\set@footnotewidth\set@footnotewidth@ii
  }{%
    \vskip6\p@
    \setbox\widetext@bot\vbox{%
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\widetext@bot}%
    \vskip10\p@
    }%
    \dimen@\ht\widetext@bot\advance\dimen@\dp\widetext@bot
    \cleaders\box\widetext@bot\vskip\dimen@
    \twocolumngrid\global\@ignoretrue
    \@endpetrue
  }%



  \def\bibfont{\normalsize}
    \def\bibsection{%
      \def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{5.5mm}{5mm}
        {\noindent\fontsize{11pt}{11pt}\selectfont$\null$\color{templateart@color}\vskip6mm \hbox{\hskip-2mm\color{templateart@color}\vrule width79.8mm height.5pt}\vskip-10mm }}
      \let\@hangfroms@section\@hang@froms
      \section*{\refname}%
      \iftemplateart@twocolumns
      \else
        \vskip-\baselineskip
        \vskip4mm
        \null
      \fi
      \@nobreaktrue
    }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \def\tiny{\fontsize{5pt}{6pt}\selectfont}
  \def\scriptsize{\fontsize{6pt}{7pt}\selectfont}
  \def\footnotesize{\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}\selectfont}
  \def\small{\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont}
  \def\normalsize{\fontsize{9pt}{18pt}\selectfont}
  \def\large{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
  \def\Large{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
  \def\LARGE{\fontsize{15pt}{16pt}\selectfont}
  \def\huge{\fontsize{17pt}{20pt}\selectfont}
  \def\Huge{\fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\selectfont}
  \def\*{$\bullet$ \relax}

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
  \abovedisplayskip=16ptplus4ptminus8pt
  \abovedisplayshortskip=1ptplus4pt
  \belowdisplayskip=16ptplus4ptminus8pt
  \belowdisplayshortskip=8ptplus6ptminus5pt

\RequirePackage{amsthm, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb}
  \newtheoremstyle{itstyle}
    {16pt plus6pt}
    {16pt plus6pt}
    {\rmfamily\it\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
    {0pt}
    {\fontsize{10}{11} \bfseries \selectfont\color{templateart@color}$\null$}
    {\newline\nobreak}
    {0pt}
    {\indent#1\hbox{ }#2\thmnote{\hbox{ }(#3)}. \ }
  \newtheoremstyle{rmstyle}
    {16pt plus6pt}
    {16pt plus6pt}
    {\rmfamily\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
    {0pt}
    {\fontsize{10}{11}\bfseries \selectfont\color{templateart@color}$\null$}
    {\newline\nobreak}
    {0pt}
    {\indent#1\hbox{ }#2\thmnote{\hbox{ }(#3)}. \ }
    
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
  \theoremstyle{itstyle}
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
  \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
  \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
  \newtheorem{claim}{Claim}[section]
  \newtheorem{fact}{Fact}[section]
  \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
  \newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[section] %???
  \newtheorem{algoritheorem}{Algoritheorem}[section] %???
  \theoremstyle{rmstyle}
  \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
  \newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
  \newtheorem{question}{Question}[section]
  \newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[section]
  \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
  \newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}[section] %???
  \def\proofname{{\fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont\color{templateart@color}$\null$Proof. \ }}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\iftemplateart@pdf
  \RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
  \RequirePackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\RequirePackage{color}
  \definecolor{templateart@color}{rgb}{1,0,0}
    \definecolor{abs}{rgb}{1,.9,.9}
  \definecolor{grey}{rgb}{.3,.3,.3}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\templateart{templateart}
\ifx\templateart@type\templateart
  \definecolor{abs}{rgb}{1,.9,.9}
  \definecolor{grey}{rgb}{.3,.3,.3}
\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\iftemplateart@pdf
  \iftemplateart@final
    \RequirePackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,final]{hyperref}
  \else
    \RequirePackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,draft]{hyperref}
  \fi
  
\else
  \iftemplateart@final
    \RequirePackage[ps2pdf,colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,final]{hyperref}
  \else
    \RequirePackage[ps2pdf,colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,draft]{hyperref}
  \fi
\fi

\usepackage{hypernat}

%%%
%\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
%            linkcolor = blue,
%            urlcolor  = blue,
%            citecolor = blue,
%            anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\templatearthref}[3][blue]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}%
%%%          
            
\paperwidth=210mm
\paperheight=277mm

\iftemplateart@pdf
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\fi

\textwidth=159.95mm
\textheight=222.5mm

\newdimen\templateart@textwidth
\templateart@textwidth=\textwidth

\hoffset=-1in
\advance\hoffset by.5\paperwidth
\advance\hoffset by-.5\textwidth

\voffset=-1in
\advance\voffset by.5\paperheight
\advance\voffset by-.5\textheight
\advance\voffset by-15mm

\evensidemargin=0mm
\oddsidemargin=0mm

\topmargin=0pt

\headheight=40pt
\headsep=0pt

\marginparsep=0pt
\marginparwidth=0pt
\marginparpush=0pt

\parindent=0pt

\baselineskip=12pt

\footskip=30pt

\def\templateart@linenumbers{}
\def\templateart@titlehead{\vbox to40pt{\hsize=.5\templateart@textwidth \advance\hsize by.5\columnsep
  \templateart@linenumbers%
}}

\def\templateart@oddhead{\vbox to40pt{%
  \iftemplateart@twocolumns
      \hsize=.5\templateart@textwidth
      \advance\hsize by.5\columnsep
  \else
    \hsize=\templateart@textwidth
  \fi
  \templateart@linenumbers%
  \def\email##1{}\def\inst##1{}%
  \vbox to20pt{%
    \raggedright%
    \fontsize{7pt}{8.4pt}\selectfont\color{grey}%
    \ifx\templateart@shortauthor\empty%
      \templateart@author%
    \else%
      \templateart@shortauthor%
    \fi%
    \vss%
  }%
  \hbox to\templateart@textwidth{\hskip-2mm\color{templateart@color}\vrule width\textwidth height.5pt\hss}%
  \vskip1mm
  \hskip.5\templateart@textwidth\hbox to.5\templateart@textwidth{\hskip.5\columnsep\color{white}\vrule width\textwidth height2.962mm\hss}%
  \vss%
}}

\def\templateart@evenhead{\vbox to40pt{\hsize=\templateart@textwidth
  \templateart@linenumbers%
  \def\email##1{}\def\inst##1{}%
  \vbox to20pt{%
    \raggedleft%
    \fontsize{7pt}{8.4pt}\selectfont\color{grey}%
    \ifx\templateart@shorttitle\empty%
      \templateart@title%
    \else%
      \templateart@shorttitle%
    \fi%
    \vss%
  }%
  \hbox to\templateart@textwidth{\hss\color{templateart@color}\vrule width\textwidth height.5pt\hskip 0mm}%
  \vskip1mm
  \hbox to.5\templateart@textwidth{\hss\color{white}\vrule width\textwidth height2.962mm\hskip.5\columnsep}%
  \vss%
}}

    
    
\def\templateart@oddfoot{\iftemplateart@printpagenumbers%
    \hfill\rlap{\hskip.7cm{\colorbox{white}{\hbox to1.7cm{%
    \hss\usefont{T1}{square721exeu}{m}{n}\fontsize{7pt}{8.4pt}\selectfont\color{black}\thepage\hss}}}}%
  \fi}

\def\templateart@evenfoot{\iftemplateart@printpagenumbers%
    \llap{{\colorbox{white}{\hbox to1.7cm{%
    \hss\fontsize{7pt}{8.4pt}\selectfont\color{black}\thepage\hss}}\hskip.7cm}}%
  \fi}

\def\ps@myheadings{
  \let\@oddhead=\templateart@oddhead
  \let\@oddfoot=\templateart@oddfoot
  \let\@evenhead=\templateart@evenhead
  \let\@evenfoot=\templateart@evenfoot
}

\def\ps@titlepage{
  \let\@oddhead=\templateart@titlehead
  \let\@oddfoot=\templateart@oddfoot
  \let\@evenhead=\templateart@titlehead
  \let\@evenfoot=\templateart@evenfoot
}

\ps@myheadings

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
  \fontfamily{\familydefault}

  \thispagestyle{titlepage}
  \def\templateart@lastpage{{\color{red}[Compile the document one more time to update number of the last page!]}}

  \newread\templateart
  \openin\templateart=\jobname.templateart
  \ifeof\templateart \else\input\jobname.templateart \fi

  \newwrite\templateart
  \immediate\openout\templateart=\jobname.templateart

  \rm\normalsize
}

\AtEndDocument{
  \immediate\write\templateart{\string\lastpage{\thepage}}
  \immediate\closeout\templateart
}
\endinput
```

**I edited the name of the class**
*Using Overleaf makes it easy to compie by uploading the two files together with the picture

Comment: Do not call your class article.cls. This name is reserved for the standard classes. Everyone using your class and looking for help on the internet will heavily confuse everyone if they show sample code.

Comment: And better don't base anything on revtex4 as it is obsolete.

Comment: Why are you developing a class template?  That's complicated stuff, and you've already tripped over a few easy mistakes.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Ultrike, Yes, that true. I've changed the name of the class accordingly.